# Java: How to check if a Key is mapped in a HashMap?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

How do I check if a Key is mapped in a HashMap?

Here is my code:

```
    currencyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    currencyMap.put("USD", "US Dollar");
    currencyMap.put("EUR", "Euro");
    currencyMap.put("GBP", "British Pound Sterling");
    currencyMap.put("JPY", "Japanese Yen");
    currencyMap.put("CAD", "Canadian Dollar");
    currencyMap.put("AUD", "Australian Dollar"); 

    String checkCurrency = "CHF"; // Swiss Franc

    // List Keys
    for (String key : currencyMap.keySet() ) {
    String value = currencyMap.get( key );
    System.out.println( key + " = " + value);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
boolean isMapped = currentMap.containsKey(checkCurrency);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have questions like these in the future, try to find the `HashMap` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and then you will be able to determine very quickly what to use.

In this case you can use  [HashMap#containsKey(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) or if you want to find if the value is in the `HashMap`, you can use [HashMap#containsValue(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29).